# Urn problem Probability - expectation value

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

We have two urns. You can't tell them apart from the outside, but one has three \$1 chips and seven \$10 chips, and the other has eight \$1 chips and two \$10 chips. You randomly draw a chip from one of the urns and it happens to be a $10 chip. Without replacing this draw, I offer you a chance to draw and keep a chip from either urn. Should you draw from the same urn or the opposite urn, and what is the expected value of the chip you draw? Why?

I did by casework,
say we had drawn from 1st urn , then E(2nd time 1st urn)=\$7, E(2nd time 2nd urn)=\$7.3
say we had drawn from 2nd urn , then E(2nd time 1st urn)=\$6.4, E(2nd time 2nd urn)=\$8
so finally E(2nd time same urn)=0.5*7+0.5*8 = 7.5
E(2nd time other urn)=0.5*7.3+0.5*6.4 = 6.85
so same urn is favourable. Now this answer is incorrect. But I cannot find my mistake. Help!

Comment: We are given the information that we had successfully drawn a $\$10$ chip which leads us to believe we are more likely to have drawn from the first urn for our initial draw.

Comment: For a handwavy explanation, if we were to have labeled each of the chips uniquely there are nine different $\$10$ chips we might have drawn, each of which happen to have been equally likely to have been the chip we pulled, seven of which originated from the first urn.  The correct value then, $\frac{7}{9}\times \frac{6\times 10 + 3\times 1}{9} + \frac{2}{9}\times\frac{1\times 10+8\times 1}{9}$ for the expected value of not switching

Comment: Yes thanks, I did a calculation error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X$ be the event the first chip drawn was worth $\$1$.  Let $A$ be the event the first chip was drawn from the first urn, what I'll hereafter refer to as "urn $A$."  Similarly, $B$ will be the event $A^c$, the event of drawing from urn $B$.  Let $Y$ be the random variable corresponding to the value of the second drawn chip, that is $Y=10$ is the event where we draw a $\$10$ chip and $Y=1$ is the event where we draw a $\$1$ chip.

We are tasked with calculating $E[Y\mid X]$ given the strategy of not switching as well as $E[Y\mid X]$ given the strategy of always switching.

Now... while true, $\Pr(A)=0.5$, this shouldn't appear in your calculations where it did.  What is more relevant is $\Pr(A\mid X) = \frac{3}{11}$.  This calculation is able to be conveniently and immediately performed thanks to the symmetry of the problem where each of the $11$ chips worth $\$1$ were equally likely to have been drawn, three of which originated from urn $A$.

If you insist on calculating $\Pr(A\mid X)$ the long way, approach with Bayes' Theorem, $\Pr(A\mid X) = \dfrac{\Pr(X\mid A)\Pr(A)}{\Pr(X)} = \dfrac{\frac{3}{10}\cdot\frac{1}{2}}{\frac{3}{10}\cdot\frac{1}{2}+\frac{8}{10}\cdot\frac{1}{2}} = \frac{3}{11}$

Now... $\Pr(Y=10\mid X) = \frac{\Pr(Y=10\cap X)}{\Pr(X)}=\frac{\Pr(X)\Pr(A\mid X)\Pr(Y=10\mid X,A) + \Pr(X)\Pr(B\mid X)\Pr(Y=10\mid X,B)}{\Pr(X)}$

The $\Pr(X)$ can cancel top and bottom, leaving you with:

$\Pr(A\mid X)\Pr(Y=10\mid X,A) + \Pr(B\mid X)\Pr(Y=10\mid X,B)$

I already covered how to calculate $\Pr(A\mid X)$.  As for $\Pr(Y=10\mid X,A)$, that is as simple as looking at how many chips are still in the specified urn of the appropriate value after noting one of the $\$1$'s was taken out and is $\frac{7}{9}$

So, we have $\Pr(Y=10\mid X) = \frac{3}{11}\cdot\frac{7}{9} + \frac{8}{11}\cdot\frac{2}{9}$

We can similarly calculate $\Pr(Y=1\mid X)$.  We calculate then $E[Y\mid X] = 10\Pr(Y=10\mid X)+1\Pr(Y=1\mid X) = \frac{48}{11}\approx 4.36$ for not switching.

For switching it is similar except $\Pr(Y=10\mid X,A)$ will have to do with the contents of urn $B$ instead of the remaining contents of urn $A$ yielding $\frac{334}{55}\approx 6.07$ for switching.

This agrees with our intuition... if we had drawn a $\$1$ chip, we should have thought it more likely that we were previously drawing from the urn with a larger proportion of $\$1$ chips and we should want to switch to improve our expected result.